# Sgen errors produced by .NET Reflector

Tags: sgen, post-build, .net-reflector

I put an **sgen.exe** command in target (post-build) of my project's .csproj.
It works fine, the command generate XmlSerializers.dll and project uses it as expected.

The problem comes when someone that has the project also uses **.NET Reflector**  to decompile and debug some referenced **third party** assemblies, at this point when you recompile the project sgen.exe command throw an error because it **can't load the assembly or one of its dependencies**, this is because the external referenced assemblies has some tipical Sgen errors as "types with the same name", "two classes using the same custom type", etc. 
As third party assemblies I can't modify it... And no use .NET Reflector is not an option...
Is there any solution? or an option in reflector to solve it? or anyone knows why Sgen try to preserialize types of this assemblies?

Thanks for advance...

Comment: Contact Redgate for support with their product.

Comment: Thanks. I'm waiting for his response, but if someone has a solution it will be wonderful hehe